# python read/write data IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to write a simply code to extract specific data columns from my measurement results (.txt files) and then save them into a new text file. Unfortunately I'm already stuck even before the writing part. The code below results in a following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`
How do I solve this? It seems to be related to the size of the data, i.e. the same code worked for a much smaller data file.

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')

header1 = f.readline()
header2 = f.readline()
header3 = f.readline()

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    name = columns[2]
    j = columns[3]
    print(name, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using index you should check the length of the `split()` result or check the line's pattern by using a regex.

Example of length check to add right after the `columns = line.split()` :

```
if len(columns) < 4:
    continue
```

So if you have a line that does not match your awaited data format it won't crash